# Less.js - strong nested rules?

Tags: css, less

I love the ability of less.js to make nested rules. For example

```
.A{
    .B{
        width:50px;
    }
}
```

which results in

```
.A .B{
    width:50px;
}
```

But is there a way to make it result in this:

```
.A > .B{
    width:50px;
}
```

I´ve already tried to do this:

```
.A{
    &>.B{
        width:50px;
    }
}
```

But it does not work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
.A {
    > .B {
        width: 50px;
    }
}
```

Another related question: [Immediate Child selector in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110286/immediate-child-selector-in-less)

Some documentation: http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules
*(doesn't actually include relevant example)*