# Immediate Child selector in LESS

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

Is there anyway to have LESS apply the immediate child selector ( > ) in its output?

In my style.less, I want to write something like:

```
.panel {
    ...
    > .control {
        ...
    }
}
```

and have LESS generate something like:

```
.panel > .control { ... }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634932/less-js-strong-nested-rules

Comment: Amusingly, the snippet in your question was already the right answer.

Comment: @thirtydot Sure, except that it doesn't work... not if you don't remove the space or add the "&". I'm using less.js. Can't say for sure for other parsers.

Comment: I've just tested it, and the original code from your question *does* work in less.js. See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/vcE8t/

Comment: Yes my apologies, it works like a charm with the space. +1 for you. I don't know how it didn't work for me for hours yesterday... otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Actually, the code in the original question works fine. You can just stick with the `>` child selector.

---

Found the answer.

```
.panel {
    ...
    >.control {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note the lack of space between ">" and ".", otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that it's a bug if it doesn't work with a space there, unless it's specifically documented.

Comment: This is just fooling the parser. It sees it as a single selector, so you get `.panel >.control`.

Comment: I take it as a feature rather than a bug. It's much more consistent when you use it this way as opposed to the "&". I think it's clearer code if you only use "&" with pseudo-classes and not child classes.

Comment: It's a feature of CSS, which accepts both `div > p` and `div>p`. Consistency would be always using space between selectors (take a look at the generated CSS).

Comment: Sure, but I was more concerned with the consistency of using &.

Comment: Is it possible to place the `>` after the `.panel `?

Answer (score 80):

The official way:

```
.panel {
  & > .control {
    ...
  }
}
```

`&` always refers to the current selector.

See http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules

Comment: I think this is also just fooling the parser (like you felt about the other answer). Let me explain. Like you said, & always refers to the current (parent) selector. So whatever that's after it should **apply** to the parent. And, that's pseudo-classes' role. Immediate child classes are closer to ****gasp**** child classes rather than pseudo-classes. So using just > is more intuitive and logical.

Comment: What do you think is more correct? `div > p` or `div >p`? The `&` combinator is the canonical way do it in LESS, not my feelings. Your explanation is rethorical. Some people write their CSS in a single line...

Comment: Most people use LESS so they don't have to care about the actual CSS that gets generated. Anyhow, it turns out that space can be used after >. So & is purely redundant.

Answer (score 14):

The correct syntax would be following while using '&' would be redundant here.

```
.panel{
   > .control{
   }
}
```

According to [less guidelines](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-multiple-), '&' is used to parameterize ancestors (but there is no such need here). In [this less example](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-multiple-), *&:hover* is essential over *:hover* otherwise it would result in syntactic error. However, there is no such syntactic requirement for using '&' here. Otherwise all nestings would require '&' as they are essentially referring to parent.

Comment: @JJF no question because it is an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In case that you need to target more selectors:

```
.parent {
    >.first-child,
    >.second-child,
    >.third-child {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, If you are targeting the first child element, such as the first `<td>` of a `<tr>`, you could use something like this:

```
tr {
    & > td:first-child {font-weight:bold;}
}
```

this helps reduce class declarations when they aren't needed.