# Ampersand in Less.js vs. SCSS

Tags: css, less, sass

I was about to switch from SCSS to Less.js, but I can't find one functionality which I was used to use with SCSS.

```
#nav {
  li a {
    color: maroon;

    body.admin & {background-color: #eee;}
  }
}
```

Here it says that defines that `#nav li a` in context of `body.admin` will have a gray background.

```
#nav {
  &>li {
     ...
  }
}
```

Correspond to `#nav>li {...}`.

These are not possible with less.js?

Comment: I don't think you can do the `body.admin &` thing with LESS. Probably not a bad thing, because it's confusing. For `>`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7635074/405015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do the `body.admin &` thing with LESS. Probably not a bad thing, because it's confusing.

For `>` (child selector), see: [Less.js - strong nested rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634932/less-js-strong-nested-rules/7635074#7635074)

> **See:** http://tinkerbin.com/H3wUpFMj *(change the CSS format to "Less", then press "Run")*
>
> It's as simple as this:
>
> ```
> .A {
>     > .B {
>         width: 50px;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this usage of & is [supported in LESS](http://lesscss.org/#-advanced-usage-of-&).

You can see this if you enter your example into http://less2css.org:

LESS Input:

```
#nav {
  li a {
    color: maroon;

    body.admin & {background-color: #eee;}
  }
}
```

CSS Output:

```
#nav li a {
  color: maroon;
}
body.admin #nav li a {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```